# ¿Por qué desaparece mi botón al seleccionar un elemento de mi dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Tengo un botón de servidor que esta dentro de un `update panel` para evitar el `postback`, este botón aparece debajo de mi `grid` después de dar clic a otro botón para consultar los registros usando `ajax` y `asp.net c#`.

Al principio todo funciona como se espera el botón no se muestra al iniciar la pagina y solo es visible después de consultar los datos.

Mi problema es que después de consultar los datos y volver a seleccionar en mi `dropdownlist` anidado el botón desaparece.

Este es mi código.

```js
// Este es mi codigo ajax al momento de consultar los datos.


function obtener_datos() {


    var id_persona = 1;
    
    
    if (persona != 0) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersona.aspx/Persona",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"' + id_persona + '"}',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
        
        // Al hacer la consulta  correctamente hago visible el boton notificacion.
           
           $("[id*=btnNotificacion]").css("display", "block");
           $("[id*=btnNotificacion]").attr("disabled", false);
           
            }

         }
     }
```

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="row">                
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCiudad" runat="server" Text="Ciudad" ></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCiudad" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCiudad_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>                    
                 </div>
                <br />               
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartamento" runat="server" Text="Departamento"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartamento" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                         
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <br /> 
                <br /> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 offset-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
                        onclick="return obtener_datos();"><span class="fas fa-search"></span></button>  
                     </div>     
                </div>
                
                
     </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


<div class="col-lg-3">
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>           
                 <%-- Este es el boton que desaparece al seleccionar por segunda vez un elemento del dropdownlist--%>
                       
       <asp:Button ID="btnNotificacion" runat="server" Text="Notificacion" Style="display:none"
                             CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                             onclick="btnNotificacion_Click"/>
                             
            </ContentTemplate>  
        </asp:UpdatePanel>     
 
                    </div>
```

En el código de `c#` tengo esto.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = t.Listar_Ciudad();
        ddlCiudad.DataSource = t.Listar_Ciudad);
        ddlCiudad.DataTextField = "Nombre_Ciudad".ToString();
        ddlCiudad.DataValueField = "id_Ciudad".ToString();
        ddlCiudad.DataBind();
   }


protected void ddlCiudad_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int id_Ciudad = Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlCiudad.SelectedValue);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = t.Listar_Departamento(id_Ciudad);
            ddlDepartamento.DataSource = dt;
            ddlDepartamento.DataTextField = "Nombre_Departamento".ToString();
            ddlDepartamento.DataValueField = "id_Departamento".ToString();
            ddlDepartamento.DataBind();


       }
    }
```

> Nota: Todo me lo hace correctamente lo único que quiero evitar es que no desaparezca el botón cuando se consultan los datos una vez por segunda vez.

Comment: Prueba quitando el "display: none" del botón, luego asigna el ocultamiento cuando se ingresa a la página: $( document ).ready(function() {
    // Aquí ocultar el boton
});

Comment: Hola @AlonsoFallas gracias por tu ayuda he podido solucionarlo. Seguí los pasos como me recomendaste pero aun tenia el problema que al seleccionar la primera vez los dropdown aparecía el botón y he solucionado esto colocando en el update panel del boton esta instrucción UpdateMode="Conditional"

Comment: Perfecto me alegro, si pudieras publicar la solución como respuesta po si otras personas la necesitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así es como arregle mi problema, La única instrucción que coloque fue **UpdateMode="Conditional"** en el HTML del UpdatePanel del botón. El código ajax y del lado del servidor se quedaron iguales.

```js
// Este es mi codigo ajax al momento de consultar los datos.


function obtener_datos() {


    var id_persona = 1;
    
    
    if (persona != 0) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersona.aspx/Persona",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"' + id_persona + '"}',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
        
        // Al hacer la consulta  correctamente hago visible el boton notificacion.
           
           $("[id*=btnNotificacion]").css("display", "block");
           $("[id*=btnNotificacion]").attr("disabled", false);
           
            }

         }
     }
```

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="row">                
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCiudad" runat="server" Text="Ciudad" ></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCiudad" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCiudad_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>                    
                 </div>
                <br />               
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartamento" runat="server" Text="Departamento"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartamento" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                         
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <br /> 
                <br /> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 offset-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
                        onclick="return obtener_datos();"><span class="fas fa-search"></span></button>  
                     </div>     
                </div>
                
                
     </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


<div class="col-lg-3">
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>           
                 <%-- Este es el boton que desaparece al seleccionar por segunda vez un elemento del dropdownlist--%>
                       
       <asp:Button ID="btnNotificacion" runat="server" Text="Notificacion" Style="display:none"
                             CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                             onclick="btnNotificacion_Click"/>
                             
            </ContentTemplate>  
        </asp:UpdatePanel>     
 
                    </div>
```

Este es el código del lado del servidor.

```
private void Page_Load()
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = t.Listar_Ciudad();
    ddlCiudad.DataSource = t.Listar_Ciudad);
    ddlCiudad.DataTextField = "Nombre_Ciudad".ToString();
    ddlCiudad.DataValueField = "id_Ciudad".ToString();
    ddlCiudad.DataBind();
   }


 protected void ddlCiudad_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int id_Ciudad = Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlCiudad.SelectedValue);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = t.Listar_Departamento(id_Ciudad);
        ddlDepartamento.DataSource = dt;
        ddlDepartamento.DataTextField = "Nombre_Departamento".ToString();
        ddlDepartamento.DataValueField = "id_Departamento".ToString();
        ddlDepartamento.DataBind();


   }
}
```